# Strangest Issue With IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session

I'll try to be as specific as possible. I know this is impossible to debug without being able to replicate the issue but maybe somebody can advise how I can go about debugging this because I'm all out of options.

I have an application which allows the user to select screenshots and then print them. When they click print, it takes the user to a new page and displays the images in a minimal template. The user then prints from that page straight in the browser.

The user's selection of images is passed over using a session. In EVERY other browser that session is correctly obtained and the images are displayed. In MOST people's IE this is also the case. However in MY IE and a few others, the session is not there..wait for it..until you *manually* press the refresh button.

I'm so on the verge of completely canceling support for IE but the better developer in me tells me I have to get through this somehow.

I tried a meta refresh if no session. The page just keeps refreshing. The session is not obtained until I literally press the refresh button.

I have tried:

deleting cache, disabling cache, deleting all temp internet files, using IE Tester and testing other IE versions. I'm on Win 7 64 bit if that makes any difference.

I'm at my wits end with this. I can't tell you how much I'd appreciate advice.

Comment: Seems related to [PHP session problem *only in IE* *(??? really strange problem)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306132/php-session-problem-only-in-ie-really-strange-problem).

Comment: Thanks! I think there are a couple of things on that page and a few other links from that page which could help so thank you very much! Still, sadly, there are no blank attributes on my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *ONLY* solution I found to this was to use Javascript to refresh the page! Meta refresh didn't work.

This is perhaps the most ridiculous solution I've ever had to hack together.

Microsoft should stop trying to create browsers.