# PHP session ID reset in IE

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I have a page with just this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id();
?>
```

running on localhost. In IE my session id gets reset with every page load (i.e. the session is reset, all old session info is lost). In any other browser it works just fine and my session id doesn't change on refresh.

This happens in browsers mode IE7, IE8 and IE9 (actual browser = IE9). I've got IE privacy (cookies) settings on 'Accept all cookies'. Yet in developer tools 'cache->view cookie info' nothing is shown. Clearing all session cookies doesn't help either, nor does clearing browser cache. Though, in the PHP session storage dir a new session file is created at each refresh.

php session config:

```
session.auto_start Off Off
session.bug_compat_42 On On
session.bug_compat_warn On On
session.cache_expire 180 180
session.cache_limiter nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain no value no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0 0
session.cookie_path / /
session.cookie_secure Off Off
session.entropy_file no value no value
session.entropy_length 0 0
session.gc_divisor 1000 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime 1440 1440
session.gc_probability 1 1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5 5
session.hash_function 0 0
session.name PHPSESSID PHPSESSID
session.referer_check no value no value
session.save_handler files files
session.save_path D:\webserver\environment\temp\sessions D:\webserver\environment\temp\sessions
session.serialize_handler php php
session.use_cookies On On
session.use_only_cookies On On
session.use_trans_sid 0 0
```

So the weird thing is this happens only on IE, no other browsers and IE seems to be configured correctly...

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306132/php-session-doesnt-work-with-ie

Comment: Does the setting 'Accept all cookies' include the **Local intranet**, or did you make this setting for the **Internet** zone only?

Comment: @martinstoeckli Yes, I set it for the local intranet as I'm testing on localhost. It's a good tip though as I didn't specify it in my question

Answer (score 0):

Pressing "refresh" will generally send the same request as before - even if you've cleared the cache.

Close down IE completely. Go to control panel, open "Internet Options" from there and delete the cookies. Clear cache too, if you want to be sure. Then open IE and have another go.